# Xcode - Change view using Navigation Bar Button Item and Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm making an app with multiple views, using a Navigation Controller. I can easily change views by ctrl-dragging from a button to another view, but it doesn't work by doing the same thing, but with a button in the Navigation Bar.

At first, I had a warning about the style of the button, so I changed it from Plain to Bordered. I have no warning now, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of button did you place in the navigation bar? UIButton or UIBarButton?

Comment: I took a UIButton from the objects list and dragged it in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it again but using a UIBarButton, then link the push action to it and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! One last question : how can I set this button with the "Info Light" type like a regular button? I have a bunch of types (or Identifiers), but the Info Light isn't there.

Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I finally got it, I will post it here if anyone has the same problem. The way I did it is by using a UIButton (not UIBarButton). So I dragged a UIButton on the interface, changed the type to "Info Light", made the connection using ctrl + drag, and finally dragging it in the Navigation Bar. I had to do it in this order.

Comment: Thank you @Looler. I had the same problem, too. Your solution worked smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the button and drag the circle next to "Push" under Storyboard Segues over to the view you want the button to navigation to.

Comment: That's what I was doing, as I said it works with regular buttons in the View, but it doesn't work with a button in the Navigation Bar.